# Percentage width of divs (tiles)

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, percentage

I need to make divs like "tiles" side-by-side with percentage width (to make it dynamic to browser size), but now i have a problem that when I set margin and two tiles has 50%, they are under each other. I need to make them side-by-side. Here's my code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="contentContainer">
    <div id="content">
        <div class="bigTile"></div><div class="mediumTile"></div><div class="mediumTile"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    padding: 5px;
}

.bigTile {
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: orange; 
    width: 100%; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.mediumTile {
    display: inline-block; 
    background-color: purple; 
    width: 50%; 
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 5px; 
    padding: 0px; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

And here is jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dQMZ5/

Any idea how to make it? I want to create also 25% tiles, but I am stucked with 50% and i think solution will be same...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that "width: 50%" defines the size of content + padding + border - margins. i.e. Margins are then added to the already calculated width.

Side-by-side will work under two conditions:

- The tiles should have no margins. If you need margins to improve visual appearance, place additional divs with margins into tiles:

```
<div class="bigTile"><div class="content"></div></div>
```

- The tiles should be styled with "float: left" ("display: inline-block" can be omitted).

I forked your jsfiddle to demonstrate the solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/akhikhl/23Y8H/1/

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do it http://jsfiddle.net/jamestoone/dQMZ5/11/. This will give you equal column widths. I have changed the margins to percentages. Although if this layout is just for css3 browsers thens you can use the calc feature to say width=50%-20px. If you would like that solution then I can offer it

```
<div id="contentContainer">
<div id="content">
    <div class="big Tile"></div>
    <div class="medium Tile"></div>
    <div class="medium Tile"></div>
    <div class="small Tile"></div>
    <div class="small Tile"></div>
    <div class="small Tile"></div>
    <div class="small Tile"></div>
</div>
```

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
#contentContainer {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}

#content {
    padding: 5px;
}

.Tile {
    float: left;
    height: 50px; 
    margin: 1%; 
}

.big.Tile {
    background-color: orange; 
    width: 98%; 
}

.medium.Tile {
    background-color: purple; 
    width: 48%; 
}

.small.Tile {
    background-color: lightblue; 
    width: 23%; 
}
```